# SCP from remote to local does not work

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, scp, raspbian

I can scp just fine from local to remote by doing:

```
scp trip3.csv pi@192.168.2.11:/home/pi/
```

But when I try to do remote to local (below) it says no such file or directory:

```
scp pi@192.168.2.11:/home/pi/trip3.csv /Users/andrew/Desktop
```

When i try `scp pi@192.168.2.11:/home/pi/image.jpg ~` it asks for my remote password and shows that the transfer went through, but i can't find the file on my local machine.

also, when i go from remote to local, why does it ask me for my remote password. shouldn't it ask me for my local password?

Any thoughts?

---

How I figured out my issue:

I was initially trying to use scp while ssh'd into the raspbery pi, from the raspberry pi command line.  I did not realize you could only scp from your local machine.

My issue was solved when I scp'd from my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you’re using a Mac and copying to/from a Raspberry Pi, is that correct? (Not that it matters particularly, it’s just so my explanations are clearer.)

Regardless of the “direction” of the copy, `scp` always asks for the remote password. You’re running commands on your Mac, so you’ve already proved that you know how to access the local end (the Mac); you need to prove that you know how to access the remote (the Raspberry Pi), so `scp` asks for the remote password.

If copying from a remote computer to the local computer asked for your local password, you could copy any file from anywhere using only your local password... Imagine if

```
scp `larry@somemachine.google.com:/home/larry/Financials.pdf` ~
```

copied that file to your computer, asking only for your password :-).

To understand the errors you’re getting, a couple of commands will help. What do

```
ssh pi@192.168.2.11 ls -l /home/pi/trip3.csv
```

and

```
ls -ld /Users/andrew/Desktop
```

say? The first checks whether `trip3.csv` really exists on the Raspberry Pi (which it should, given that your first command succeeded), and the second checks whether `/Users/andrew/Desktop` really exists on the Mac.

```
ls -l ~/image.jpg
```

should indicate where `image.jpg` ended up.